# Titan graph query

Tags: graph, bigdata, titan

Consider a vertex (V1) in Titan Graph having few out going edges having labels L1,L2,L3 and L4. Now how to find all edges from V1 having labels either L1 or L2 using TitanVertexQuery.

I have tried using GremlinPipeline, it works but unable to achieve the same using TitanVertexQuery.

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty short answer:

```
v.query().direction(Direction.OUT).labels("L1", "L2").edges()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the quick response! One question - if L1 and L2 are set as edge property ie. (type), Can we query for edges having type as either L1 or L2?

Comment: Sure, it's almost identical to Gremlin pipelines. Just do this for example: ```v.query().direction(Direction.OUT).labels("L1", "L2").has("prop1", "ABC").has("prop2", 123).edges()```.

Comment: I tried this earlier but it did not work. I am looking for edges having "prop1" property equal to either "ABC" or "123". So when I run the query v.query().direction(Direction.OUT).labels("L1", "L2").has("prop1", "ABC").has("prop1", 123).edges(), it is doing an "AND" operation not "OR" operation. ie. It is looking for edges having property "prop1" set to both "ABC" and "123". Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: That's correct, the query API only supports AND conditions. If you need OR, use 2 (or more) queries.